# how to handle blocking code in tornado's PeriodicCallback

Tags: tornado

I am using websockets with tornado.

Once I receive a message (can be "start" & "stop" in the example below), start will poll for messages from memcached every x seconds and returns json output to the websocket client.

I am using "tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback" to poll every x seconds. So the question I have is the function in this case "poll_for_new_data" has blocking code i.e. memcached gets, json.dumps to convert to json etc. How do I deal with this blocking code which I think blocks the main event loop when the calls are slow ? If you have suggestions for a different design to handle this, please let me know. I was planning to use thread pool for the blocking function, is that a good idea (or) there are better ways to do this ?

I have to use pylibmc (memcached client) for this project because it uses c++ libmemcached under the hood for a specific requirement. I cannot use a async memcache library unless it uses c++ libmemcached under the hood.

Thanks for your time

Note: I commented my CustomClass specific code as I did not share the code here.

```
from tornado import ioloop, websocket, httpserver, gen
import tornado
import json
# from custom_class import CustomClass


class CustomWebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        # for CORS
        print(origin)
        return True

    def open(self):
        print("open " + self.get_argument("user"))

    def on_message(self, message):
        message = message.lower()
        print("on_message: " + message)
        if(message == "start"):
            self.request = {"user": self.get_argument("user")}
            #self.all_pids = set()
            #self.custom_class = CustomClass(self.request)
            # poll for data every x seconds
            self.periodic_callback = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(
                self.poll_for_new_data, 10 * 1000)
            self.periodic_callback.start()
        elif(message == "stop"):
            self.close()

    def on_close(self):
        print("on_close")
        self.periodic_callback.stop()

    def poll_for_new_data(self):
        if self.ws_connection is None: 
            return

        # check for new pids
        # [queries memcached servers using pylibmc (http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/) client]
        # new_pids = self.custom_class.get_new_pids(self.all_pids)

        # if(len(new_pids) > 0):
            # if self.ws_connection is not None:
                # self.write_message(json.dumps(new_pids))

        # there is more code here which I did not include 
        # i.e. this function pools for process that register themselves 
        # and each process has messages. so every time this method is called
        # we are looking for new PIDs and new messages for each PID
        # sending the result to websocket client in JSON format


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/ws', CustomWebSocketHandler)
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    # http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 2):

In general I would recommend using a looping coroutine instead of a PeriodicCallback: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html#running-in-the-background

This will make it easier to use a thread pool to manage the blocking calls; just use `yield thread_pool.submit(f)`. If you try to submit tasks to a thread pool with a PeriodicCallback, it can be tricky to ensure that overruns don't lead to multiple requests running in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try it out and post my findings here. sorry got caught up with other things currently

Comment: @StudentForever, what were your findings?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it sounds like a bad idea bind a new periodic poller to each websocket instance that is opened. Why not implement a separate poller, as a separate worker process on your server, and have it publish updates when they occur.

You could use Redis' pubsub for subscribing each websocket instance to a Redis channel and publish from the polling worker on every update.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, I will give your approach a shot and post my findings here.